# nzsql: error while loading shared libraries: libcom_err.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: security, sql

I am trying to install Netezza Client on an Ubuntu 18.04 system. After installation once we checked, we saw the error message below

```
/usr/local/nz$ nzsql
nzsql: error while loading shared libraries: libcom_err.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

My diagnostic steps:

1. Find shared libs

   ```
   /usr/local/nz$ ldd ./bin/nzsql
   linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f13000)
   libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7ee0000)
   libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/./bin/../lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0xf7e3a000)
   libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0xf7e08000)
   libssl.so.10 => /usr/local/nz/./bin/../lib/libssl.so.10 (0xf7da5000)
   libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/local/nz/./bin/../lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0xf7bf2000)
   libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf7bda000)
   libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0xf7bbf000)
   libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7bba000)
   libncurses.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0xf7b94000)
   libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7a92000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf78b4000)
   libcom_err.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/./bin/../lib/libcom_err.so.3 (0xf78b1000)
   libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/./bin/../lib/../lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xf7882000)
   libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/local/nz/./bin/../lib/../lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xf7879000)
   libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/local/nz/./bin/../lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xf783e000)
   /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f15000)
   libcom_err.so.2 => not found
   libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xf781b000)
   ```

   I saw a "not found" message

   ```
   libcom_err.so.2 => not found
   ```
2. Try to install package

   ```
   /usr/local/nz$ sudo apt-get install libcomerr2
   [sudo] password for ocmsapp:
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   libcomerr2 is already the newest version (1.44.1-1ubuntu1.2).
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
     linux-headers-4.15.0-65 linux-headers-4.15.0-65-generic linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic
   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
   ```

   It says package is already there.
3. Checked what version is already installed

   ```
   :~$ dpkg --listfiles libcom-err2
   /.
   /lib
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
   /usr
   /usr/share
   /usr/share/doc
   /usr/share/doc/libcom-err2
   /usr/share/doc/libcom-err2/changelog.Debian.gz
   /usr/share/doc/libcom-err2/copyright
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2
   ```
4. Create a soft link

   ```
   sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 libcom_err.so.2
   ```

   Then once we checked `ldd ./bin/nzsql` still we saw the not found message

   ```
    libcom_err.so.2 => not found
   ```

   and once we try to run `nzsql` command then we got below message

   ```
   /usr/local/nz$ nzsql
   nzsql: error while loading shared libraries: libcom_err.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
   ```

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Multiarch is already enabled.

Answer (score 4):

You should confirm this by running

```
file /usr/local/nz/bin/nzsql
```

but it's likely your netazza application is a 32bit application on an x86-64 (i.e. 64bit) installation; you will need to install the 32bit version of libcomerr2 like so:

```
sudo apt install libcomerr2:i386
```

as well as for any of the other system libraries it depends on.